# Error while creating a table in mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table in MySQL Cluster . but getting a error while executing below query.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_anal_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tbl_bill_bill_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `bill_value` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `calc_value` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `err` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `error_code` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tbl_bill_info_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_anal_results_tbl_bill1_idx` (`tbl_bill_bill_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_anal_results_tbl_bill1` FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_bill_bill_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_bill` (`bill_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=16570225 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

I have used same query which I used to create same table in old mysql setup. 
and I have changed ENGINE as ENGINE=ndbcluster instead of ENGINE=InnoDB

also noticed UPDATE CASCADE not working in mysql cluster.

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious.

Comment: I have changed ENGINE as ENGINE=ndbcluster instead of ENGINE=InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut from docs:
ON UPDATE CASCADE is not supported when the reference is to the parent table's primary key.

This is because an update of a primary key is implemented as a delete of the old row (containing the old primary key) plus an insert of the new row (with a new primary key). This is not visible to the NDB kernel, which views these two rows as being the same, and thus has no way of knowing that this update should be cascaded.